# What is it that makes a MSI directory "32-bit" or "64-bit"?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm getting very frustrated at the following warnings from light.exe that I'm getting when trying to use a merge module in my WiX installer project within VS2010:

```
ICE80: This 64BitComponent F_AdaptersInGac.5AE08CC6_EB8E_4F10_AB7B_CEFD0CB0F832 
       uses 32BitDirectory GAC.5AE08CC6_EB8E_4F10_AB7B_CEFD0CB0F832
```

(repeated for each file in the merge module).

Both the merge module and the product WiX files are part of the same VS2010 solution. Both merge module and product contain a `<Package>` element that specifies Platform="x64". The fragment in the merge module .wxs file looks like this:

```
<Package Id="{5AE08CC6-EB8E-4F10-AB7B-CEFD0CB0F832}" InstallerVersion="200" Languages="1033" Manufacturer="Yoyodyne Propulsion Systems" Platform="x64" />
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">

    <!-- Assemblies that go in the GAC -->
    <Directory Id="GAC" SourceName="GAC">
       <Component Id="C_AdaptersInGac" Guid="{C1C7D6F8-197D-874E-79B9-EBFEBDDCB65A}" Win64="yes">
         <File Id="F_AdaptersInGac" Name="ERPLink.Adapters.SharePoint.dll" KeyPath="yes" Assembly=".net" Source="..\Internal\Adapters\Release\Contoso.Adapters.dll" />
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Since I even put my component element inside of the `ProgramFiles64Folder` directory, and I've marked the platform as "x64", why am I getting this error? What other places control the 64-bitness of a directory in a WiX package file?

Answer (score 0):

A merge module should have an abstraction such as MergeRedirectFolder so that when you consume them in the installer you associate MergeRedirectFolder with the actual [ProgramFiles]Company\Product  target using the Directory and Merge elements.

Also if these files are meant to go into the GAC, there is a special folder identifier called GlobalAssemblyCache that can achieve this.

The following just worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <?define ComponentRules="OneToOne"?>
  <!-- SourceDir instructs IsWiX the location of the directory that contains files for this merge module -->
  <?define SourceDir="..\Deploy"?>
  <Module Id="StrongNameMM" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0">
    <Package Id="0085d1f6-e7cf-413e-ae3c-cd1a1e0afb1b" Manufacturer="StrongNameMM" InstallerVersion="200" Platform="x64" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="MergeRedirectFolder">
        <Component Id="owc457F6083DF7B557CCA84E132209AC321" Guid="9ab7d95e-7841-3ff9-ffac-87a6b7633636" Win64="yes">
          <File Id="owf457F6083DF7B557CCA84E132209AC321" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\ClassLibrary1.dll" KeyPath="yes" Assembly=".net"/>
        </Component>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Module>
</Wix>
```

Then in the main installer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment> 

    <FeatureGroup Id="features">
      <Feature Id="StrongName" Title="StrongName" Description="Installs all the files needed for StrongName" Level="1" AllowAdvertise="no" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION">
        <MergeRef Id="StrongNameMM"/>
      </Feature>
    </FeatureGroup>

    <!-- Content -->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
        <Directory Id="CompanyFolder" Name="My Company">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="StrongName">
            <Merge Id="StrongNameMM" SourceFile="$(var.StrongNameMM.TargetPath)" DiskId="1" Language="1033"/>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Finally:

```
 <Package InstallerVersion="301" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Platform="x64" />
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. What confuses me is that the files I want to add in the merge module are in the GAC, and afaik that is expressed not by special folder identifiers but by specifying the attribute Assembly=".net" on the File element. I tried moving the Component out to the TARGETDIR directory, with the same error message as a result.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are correct. It's been so long since I installed something in the GAC that I forgot [GlobalAssemblyCache] is only an InstallShield thing.